# Find Distinct IDs when the due date is always on the last day of each month

Tags: sql, distinct

I have to find distinct `ID`s throughout the whole history of each ID whose due dates are always on the last day of each month.
Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
  ID  DUE_DT
  1   1/31/2014
  1   2/28/2014
  1   3/31/2014
  1   6/30/2014
  2   1/30/2014
  2   2/28/2014
  3   1/29/2016
  3   2/29/2016
```

I want to write a code in SQL so that it gives me `ID = 1` as for this specific `ID` the due date is always on the last day of each given month.

What would be the easiest way to approach it?

Comment: What due date do you want to return for ID = 1? Since all the 4 in sample data are on the last day of the month

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please supply the desired output.

Comment: Im still trying to understand the question. Could you please help me by adding the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when extract(day from due_dt + interval '1 day') = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = count(*);
```

This uses ANSI/ISO standard functions for date arithmetic.  These tend to vary by database, but the idea is the same in all databases -- add one day and see if the day of the month is 1 for all the rows.

Comment: Thank you very much, Gordon! It works exactly how I want it. I've slightly modified it: 
select ID
from t
group by ID
having sum(case when day(cast(DUE_DT as date) + 1) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = count(*)

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL-Version** (credits to @Gordon Linoff)

```
SELECT
    ID
FROM
    <table>
GROUP BY
    ID
HAVING
    SUM(IF(day(DUE_DT + interval 1 Day) = 1, 1, 0)) = COUNT(ID);
```

**Original Answer:**

`SELECT MAX(DUE_DT) FROM <table> WHERE ID = <the desired ID>`

or if you want all MAX(DUE_DT) for each unique ID

`SELECT ID, MAX(DATE) FROM <table> GROUP BY ID`

Comment: Hello Pilan, thank you for your suggestion. But I want to create a SQL query that gives me a list of distinct IDs whose due dates are always on the last day of each month. Your query gives me smth else.

Comment: `last day of each month` the actual last day or just the highest day from data?

Comment: the actual last day. For example, for ID = 2 the last day of the month would be = '1/31/2014' but the entry is '1/30/2014'. So we cannot select this ID.

Comment: So you want only the IDs with an actual last day? Or why cant we select this ID? Tell me what the desired outcome for ID:2|Date:1/30/2014 etc is.

Comment: Hello Pilan. The desired outcome: ID = 1. We're not selecting DUE_DT. We're trying to come up with a list of distinct IDs. In our case, the only ID is ID = 1 cause its due date is always on the last day of each month.

Comment: Ok got it, thx :) Made a MySQL version aswell `SELECT
    ID
FROM
    <table>
GROUP BY
    ID
HAVING
    SUM(IF(day(DUE_DT + interval 1 Day) = 1, 1, 0)) = COUNT(ID);`

Answer (score 0):

If your using SQL Server 2012+ you can use the EOMONTH() function to achieve this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM [table]
WHERE DUE_DT = EOMONTH(DUE_DT)
```

http://rextester.com/VSPQR78701

Comment: Thank you, Ian, but if I have multiple entries per each ID when due date coincides with the end of the month, your code will display this ID in the final list. I want to make sure that at all times (all rows) coincide throughout the whole history.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is quite simple:

- you are on the last day of the month if (the month of due date) is not the same as (the month of due date + 1 day). This covers all cases across year, leap year and so on.
- from there on, if (the count of rows for one id) is the same as (the count of rows for this id which are the last day of the month) you have a winner.

I tried to write an example (not tested). You do not specify which DB so I will assume that cte (common table expression) are available. If not just put the cte as subquery.
In the same way, I am not sure that `dateadd` and `interval` work the same in all dialect.

```
with addlastdayofmonth as (
select
    id
    -- adding a 'virtualcolumn', 1 if last day of month 0 otherwise
  , if(month(dateadd(due_date, interval '1' day)) != month(due_date), 1 ,0) as onlastday
from
  table
)
select 
    id
  , count(*) - sum(onlastday) as alwayslastday 
from
  addlastdayofmonth
group by
  id
having
  -- if count(rows) == count(rows with last day) we have a winner
  halwayslastday = 0
```

Comment: Thank you, Guillaume. I'm trying to see if your code works.